# Closed-form expression for this loss minimizer?

Tags: statistics

I am trying to find a closed-form expression for the matrix $W$ which minimizes
$$l(W) = -\log |W| + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{1}{2}(w_j^Tx_i)^2.$$
I can calculate the gradient:
$$\nabla_Wl = -W^{-T} + \sum_{i=1}^n ((w_1^T x_i)x_i, \cdots, (w_d^T x_i)x_i)^T.$$

I was thinking to use the KKT conditions, but I can't figure out how to make progress on this. Could I get some advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Generally, the KKT conditions are used when you have constraints on the variable being optimized over. Do you have any constraints that are not mentioned? And I presume $|W|$ is the determinant of $W$? and are $w_j$ the rows or columns of $W$?

Comment: $w_j$ is the $j$th row of $W$, and yes $|W|$ is the determinant

Comment: No constraints, other than possibly orthogonality of $W$, though I think this is encouraged by the -\log|W| term.

Comment: I see. Is that orthogonal rows so that $WW^T = I$ or orthogonal columns, so that $W^TW = I$? I will give it a shot now. I think in the meantime it could be informative for others to write a little context--is this a loss function for some machine learning task?

Comment: Yeah, this is related to independent components analysis, assuming the sources are IID gaussian.

Comment: $W$ is a square matrix, so $WW^T = I$ iff $W^TW = I$

Comment: Here is what I did. Let $f(X,W)^T$ be the nasty term. Then $\nabla_W l=0$ if $f(X,W)=W^{-1}$ or $Wf(X,W)=I$. Check that $Wf(X,W)=XW^2 X^T$ so that we need $XW^2 X^T =I$. If the pseudo-inverse of $X$ exists, then $X^T X W^2 X^T X = X^T X$ hence $X^T X W^2 = I$, so $W^2 = (X^T X)^{-1}$.

Comment: I think my expression for the gradient is incorrect. It should be: $\nabla_W l = -\sum_{i=1}^n Wx_i^T + W^{-T}$. Setting this equal to zero gives $! = W^TW \sum_{i=1}^n x^{(i)} = W^TW \text{Tr}(XX^T)$.

Comment: In your loss function, you are considering $w_j^T$ which should be a row vector. This contradicts your statement that $w_j$ is the $j$th row of $W$. Can you comment please?

Answer (score 1):

Concentrating on the second term,
let
$\mathbf{z}_i=\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}_i$ the column vector
with $j$th coordinate given by
$(\mathbf{w}_j^T \mathbf{x}_i)$.

The sum over $j$ in the loss function denotes the squared $\ell_2$ norm of
$\mathbf{z}_i$

$$
\phi(\mathbf{W}) = 
\frac12
\sum_{i=1}^n
\| \mathbf{z}_i \|_2^2
$$

The gradient is
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{W}}
=
\sum_{i=1}^n
\mathbf{z}_i
\mathbf{x}_i^T=
\mathbf{W}
\sum_{i=1}^n
\mathbf{x}_i
\mathbf{x}_i^T
$$
The rest should follow.